# I want to add zeros in the column of the sql database and amke it of 3 digit

Tags: sql-server-2005

i want to add zeros in my column of sql database .
for example  if data is 1 then it should display 001, and if data is 11 it should display 011..and if data is 222 then do nothing bcoz it already completed 3 digits...

Comment: This is ill-advised, usually. You should keep *formatting* concerns in your UI, not your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT RIGHT('000' + CAST(1 AS VARCHAR(3)), YourColumnNameHere) AS Value
```